# Angularjs data binding with a data attribute object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have some json attached to a data attribute on a page. The json data is used to build a table in angularjs.
I'm using coffeescript and haml.

```
    app = angular.module("myApp", [])

    app.controller "TableCtrl", ($scope) ->
      $scope.table =  $("#mydata").data("myjson")


    #table{"ng-app"=>"myApp","ng-controller" =>"TableCtrl"}
      %table
        %tbody
          %tr{"ng-repeat"=>"(i,item) in table" }}"}
            %td {{item.name}}
```

The page loads the data into a table. Elsewhere on the page the json on the data attribute can be changed by a user with jquery. How can I have 2-way binding between the json data and the table? i.e I want the table to change as the json on the data attribute is changed locally.

Comment: This is a very strange use case. Why is the data coming from jQuery instead of AngularJS? If at *all* possible, you should get the data into a model/service.

Comment: I'm updating an old app that was full of jquery, just trying to understand different parts as I work through it

Comment: I would try to pull the data out as the very first priority; otherwise there is going to be a lot more headaches down the line. AngularJS is *very* different than jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to tell AngularJS to observe `$("#mydata").data("myjson")` for any changes and then update `$scope.table` when a change occurs. Try adding the following code to your controller (sorry I don't know coffeescript).

```
$scope.$watch(
    function () { return $("#mydata").data("myjson");}, 
    function(newJson) {
        $scope.table = newJson;
    },
    true
);
```

Comment: Passing strings to `$watch` only works for scope properties. You need to use a function instead.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller - Right, my careless! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No, it should say `$scope.$watch( function() { return $("#mydata").data("myjson"); }, ...)`.

Comment: Thanks @JoshDavidMiller once again. My brain is surely not working today.

Comment: @raphael_turtle - Your case needs to have the flag for comparing object for equality rather than for reference to true. Updated my answer. Try again.

Comment: @raphael_turtle - The above code is working fine. The problem has to do with that the DOM events (those associated with changing the json objects) are triggered outside of the Angular environment and thus Angular is not aware. You need to move those event handling code into the controller and call `$scope.$apply()` to notify Angular. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/C59K8S8Be8uxOcxBxtEQ) is an example that demonstrate what I said.

Comment: [Notes On AngularJS Scope Life-Cycle](http://onehungrymind.com/notes-on-angularjs-scope-life-cycle/) is a good read.